# Elastic collisions in Python/Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, physics

I have a serious problem with dealing with elastic collisions in gravitational field. I've tried to implement this in consistency with the law of conservation of energy, but it goes wrong, [as shown in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OF7B4H83Kv4). Firstly, two objects stick together, and several hundred frames after the collision, they reach enormous speeds.

The [complete code is online here](http://ubuntuone.com/0A2uIt56dopFrffklotLxE), but the method responsible for giving output velocities after a collision is this function from `world.py`:

```
def collision(self, obj1, obj2):
    R = obj1.radius + obj2.radius   # code is used to "jump back in time" to avoid penetration when there's a collision
    dx = obj1.x - obj2.x            #
    dy = obj1.y - obj2.y            #
    K = math.hypot(dx, dy)          #   
    dvx = obj1.vx - obj2.vx         #   
    dvy = obj1.vy - obj2.vy         #
    dv = math.hypot(dvx, dvy)       #
    deltat = (R - K)/dv             #
    print dv
    print deltat
    obj1.x = obj1.rect.centerx = obj1.x - obj1.vx # *deltat
    obj2.x = obj2.rect.centerx = obj2.x - obj2.vx # *deltat
    obj1.y = obj1.rect.centery = obj1.y - obj1.vy # *deltat
    obj2.y = obj2.rect.centery = obj2.y - obj2.vy # *deltat
    dx = obj2.x - obj1.x
    dy = obj2.y - obj1.x
    delta = math.hypot(dx, dy)
    nx = dx/delta
    ny = dy/delta
    vx1bc = obj1.vx * nx
    vx2bc = obj2.vx * nx
    vy1bc = obj1.vy * ny
    vy2bc = obj2.vy * ny
    vx2ac = (obj2["energy_loss"]*(vx1bc - vx2bc) + vx1bc + (obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"]*vx2bc))/((obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"])+1)
    vy2ac = (obj2["energy_loss"]*(vy1bc - vy2bc) + vy1bc + (obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"]*vy2bc))/((obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"])+1)
    vx1ac = (vx1bc + obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"]*vx2bc - obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"]*vx2ac)*obj1["energy_loss"]
    vy1ac = (vy1bc + obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"]*vy2bc - obj2["mass"]/obj1["mass"]*vy2ac)*obj1["energy_loss"]
    V1cx = obj1.vx * ny
    V1cy = obj1.vy * ny
    V2cx = obj2.vx * ny
    V2cy = obj2.vy * ny
    alfa = math.atan2(ny, nx)
    alfa_deg = math.degrees(alfa)
    v1a = math.hypot(vx1ac, vy1ac)
    v2a = math.hypot(vx2ac, vy2ac)
    obj1.vx = v1a*math.cos(alfa)+V1cx * math.sin(alfa)
    obj2.vx = v2a*math.cos(alfa)+V2cx * math.sin(alfa)
    obj1.vy = v1a*math.sin(alfa)+V1cx * math.cos(alfa)
    obj2.vy = v2a*math.sin(alfa)+V2cx * math.cos(alfa)
```

Comment: Firstly two objects stick together and several hundereds frames after collision get to enormous speeds. Vectors? I'd like to use them too, but Python doesn't have any standard implementation of vectors.

Comment: You're not obliged to stick to the Python standard library: you are allowed to write your own code!

Comment: Still that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I followed your code up to the declaration of `delta`, but I don't understand what happens after that. What does "energy_loss" represent? Also, can you explain the meanings of the variable names nx, ny, vx1bc, vx2bc, vy1bc, vy2bc, vx2ac, vy2ac, vx1ac, vy1ac, V1cx, V1cy, V2cx, V2cy, v1a, v2a?

Comment: What shape are the bounding boxes? Circles, as suggested by the `radius` attribute? Or boxes, as suggested by `rect`?

Comment: You should also post your mathematical derivation. What are all of the considerations and input variables in your computation? How does it differ from a straightforward elastic collision?

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses a lot of different variables, and they also have not-so-relative names. That makes it difficult to keep up with all the stuff, and also difficult for others to see what your program does. Maybe you should append variables to lists and access them? Also I recommend you to take a look at a great physics tutorial:
http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation